# Completely clean server from NodeJs and npm

Tags: linux, node.js, web, uninstallation, npm

I have upgraded one **nodejs** installation from `0.4.2` to `0.8.12` but, since then, the js server I have, started crashing with `seg fault`. As I inherited this application, I have no idea what was previously installed and how was it was maintained. `Npm` seems to be installed only locally, but I can't seem to call it the right way.

So this is all the info about the problem. My question is:

Can I completely remove `nodejs` and `npm` so I can do a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to install nvm .
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Use nvm to install different versions of node . Then try different versions , say 0.5 then 0.6 and 
checkout at which version does the app actually break.
And then refer to the critical changes made in that version and modify your code accordingly.

This would be a good software practice .

Comment: I have n installed and I tried with 0.7 but it still crashed. Another change I did was to update the python version. I don't know if it is related or not though. I fear that basically all dependent node_modules are not compatible with anything besides the original version, so that is why I want to install everything fresh.

Comment: Another thing. The crash always happens when I am trying to log in. In other words there is something wrong with the authentication, but I am using mongoose-auth for this. How do I update that module. Bare in mind I have only n installed and npm can't be called.

Comment: dependencies of mongoose auth state that , it requires node of version greater than or equal to 0.4.0 , so i personally dont think mongoose is posing a problem 
link https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/blob/master/package.json